Do I really need this many (DTO) types for mapping a simple object to CRUD & database?
Say I'm building my own backend framework (really I'm just learning) and I have a simple class:
class User {
    String email
    String passwordHash
    Date birthdate

    Int getAge() {
        Duration dt = Date.today() - birthdate
        return dt.years
    }

    // Imagine more methods and things like `email` validation etc.
}

To create objects of this type, I obviously don't use passwordHash but need the initial raw password instead (to hash it on the server side):
struct UserCreationDto {
    String email
    String rawPassword
    Date birthdate
}

To update objects of this type, I need yet another type because maybe email and birthdate can't be changed after the user is created:
struct UserUpdationDto {
    String rawPassword
    // Imagine there are other fields like `profilePicture` or whatever
}

When the user visits his own profile settings, he needs to see most of the existing data, but maybe not passwordHash:
struct UserSelfDto {
    String email
    Date birthdate
}

Yet when the data is displayed to another user, some other "secret" fields like exact birthdate need to be hidden as well:
struct UserPublicDto {
    String email
    Int age  // Others can only see your age, not exact date
}

And finally to store/load users to/from say a database or a JSON file, I need something similar to CreationDto but with the password hashed instead of the raw one:
struct UserStorageDto {
    String email
    String passwordHash
    Date birthdate
}

So initially I thought I'd get away with a simple mapper class:
interface Mapper<T, Dto> {
    Dto toDto(T object) 
    void updateObject(T object, Dto dto)
}

But now it looks like I need my mappers to have a dozen methods to support all edge cases and DTO types (arrow directions matter):


Is my assumption correct, or am I missing something here?
Do I really need a new type and a mapper function for every single action that can be taken on the user?
How do other existing frameworks implement support for so many different types?


No, can just use User for everything

@Ewan That makes no sense to me. I can't provide my internal User to external APIs, otherwise they can just access all secret fields and change passwords and whatever. Also I can't even transmit it over protocols like HTTP like that, I need to convert it to JSON first anyways?

Why do you consider it problematic to create custom types for each specific request? Especially in this day and age, AI easily creates exactly the DTOs and mappers for your needs in seconds. Are you facing any issues with your approach?

@RikD That's a good question I haven't really considered. I guess I just find it cumbersome, repetitive boilerplate? There have been no other issues thus far, I guess I'm just looking for a better alternative, not really a "fix".

IMO the issue I see here is a focus on data rather than behavior. It may seem insignificant but something like CreateUserRequest or UserInfo conveys a lot more information and feels more intentional even if the data is the same. DTOs like you've defined them have a way of become grab bags of data because they don't have a "place" and aren't part of a bigger picture.


Is my assumption correct, or am I missing something here?

I suspect you are missing some useful lessons about parsing; it will probably be useful to review:

Parse, Don't Validate
On the Complexity of JSON Serialization

It's normal to have a message schema that includes optional fields.
It's normal to ignore fields that don't matter when handling a message, or to use default values when optional fields are absent.
It's normal for contracts to impose additional constraints on messages (example: HTTP requests aren't required to include an Authorization header, but if you don't send me one when asking for sensitive information, you are getting a 401 Unauthorized response back).
Because GET and PUT are dual to one another, it's normal (but not required) that the body of a PUT request will use the same message as the body of a 200 OK response to a GET request.  That doesn't necessarily mean that the fields will be the same -- review the fine print in the current specification of PUT.
But those are all about the message; effectively ensuring that sender and receiver have a common understanding of how the bytes-in-a-row should be interpreted.
Your Data Transfer Object is "just" your transient in-memory representation of the message, along with some conveniently located methods, allowing the rest of your code to interface with the message "abstraction" without being coupled to the underlying data structures.

Do I really need a new type and a mapper function for every single action that can be taken on the user?

Not necessarily - but you are going to be making trade offs for every single action that can be taken on the user.  (The first trade off usually being: do I want to think about this, or automatically follow a common pattern?)

I found the On the Complexity of JSON Serialization article's Data Model Mapping section—along with the rest of your answer—extremely useful. I feel like I've been overthinking this, and sometimes we just have to do the boring job as well. Thank you.

No, you can just use User for everything.
The problem is you various vaguely defined requirements.

PasswordHash
Obviously this is an internal mechanic of authentication. Why is it part of User at all?

maybe email and birthdate can't be changed after the user is created:
Just don't update them if they have changed

data is displayed to another user, some other "secret" fields like exact birthdate need to be hidden
You are confusing the ViewModel, Domain Model and DTOs, plus whether the presentation layer can be trusted or not. If the presentation layer can't be trusted to hide the data, Then you will need some server side ViewModels yes.


Authentication is a tricky area I would not recommend writing your own but essentially you have a case for splitting your domain model into more than one object. How about..
User //public info for general user
{
   string Id
   string Name
   int Age
   Image ProfilePic
}

UserAccount //secret extra stuff
{
   User User
   Email
   DoB
}

AuthenticationService //this has extra internal objects for dealing with password hashes etc
{
   RegisterNewUser(UserAccount, password)
   UserAccount AuthenticateUser(username, password)
   ForgottenPassword(username)
   ...
}

Assuming we cant trust the client, we might also have server side view models for specific pages/screens/windows
MyFriendsPageViewModel
{
   List<User> Friends
   Dictionary<string,int> FriendRating
   UserAccount MyAccount
   bool Darkmode
   bool MenuOpen
   ...
}


"PasswordHash: Obviously this is an internal mechanic of authentication. Why is it part of User at all?" Are you asking why the user's password is part of the user? I am using the OOP paradigm, of course it is part of the user. Why is anything part of the user with your logic? ID is just part of storage, name is just part of identification, age is just a mechanic of the lifecycle!

"Just don't update them if they have changed" The client needs to be able to update data fields, period. If I provide them with the User object, they can update whatever they want without restrictions. Your answer makes no sense.

@MarkusMeskanen passwords are for authentication, birthdays usually aren’t. Ewan’s answer makes sense, but maybe not to you. If you don’t understand something, you can choose to disagree and be rude, or just ask what someone means, they might surprise you.

@RikD No, the logic applies to any field: "birthdays are for numerous validation and identification mechanics, why are they part of user?" We're talking OOP vs non-OOP approach, nothing more. Hence my earlier "I am using OOP paradigm" comment. His answer objectively makes no sense in the context of my question, which very clearly uses the OOP paradigm. Why would I suddenly change one field from my OOP approach to no longer follow the OOP approach? I didn't ask what they mean because I know what they mean and it makes no sense in this context.

@RikD And I wasn't being rude, I was simply explaining why their logic is nonsensical (again, in the context of my question). If you interpret it as being rude when someone simply states that you are wrong, then that's on you.

OOP doesn’t dictate that you add everything that’s related to something in a single type. You might want to look into the concept of Bounded Contexts.

@RikD At this point this conversation and getting hung up on any one individual field has nothing to do with my question anymore.

"Are you asking why the user's password is part of the user" Yes. "I am using the OOP paradigm, of course it is part of the user. " Its not. You should never be storing the users password, that's the whole point of hashing it. you shoul dhave some object that deals with authentication

"The client needs to be able to update data fields, period. If I provide them with the User object, they can update whatever they want without restrictions" No they cant, they have to send a User object to some updating service, which can check and apply any rules you want.

"really I'm just learning" If you want to learn you should try my suggestion and see what problems you run into. This is the solution for your current problem of "I have a million DTOs"

Also, you don't mention OOP in your question and your interpretation of what is and isnt OOP seems very strict

Is authentication of a user the responsibility of the User object? Most frameworks consider security a cross cutting concern, outside of your domain

@Ewan You should refrain from using phrases like "you should" and "you should never". There is no one correct way to write software, your way is not somehow the best that all people should follow. I shouldn't even bother trying your suggestion because I can already tell it has nothing to do with my question or issue. I have chosen my paradigm and you should not push your favorite one on me. If you can't answer the question in my chosen paradigm, you shouldn't have left an answer. You should read up more on the DTOs and why they exists.

@Ewan "No they cant, they have to send a User object to some updating service, which can check and apply any rules you want" If they (e.g. a plugin) have access to my User object, they can simply do user.name = 'trolled' and modify the object in memory past my service logic. You seem to believe I have multiple copies of User, which is not the case. Also this doesn't answer how creation data can differ from the user's internal data. It also doesn't answer how to hide certain fields. It also ignores how User is just a basic example, not my real domain model. I'm done here.

They can do that if they have the username in any form at all.

Also, you've got dtos right? so a command is being sent over the wire to some other program that actually does the update?? that program can just check to see if the created date is already set and choose not to change it . I guess what confuses me is why you have got angry about my answer. You havent gone "yes I could do this, but I also want X, and I cant see how that would work". I suppose maybe someone has already told you to do it this way and you dont want to do what they say?
